# Периодически не запускается Chrome Browser

Tags: c#, .net, chromedriver

Может быть кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой. При запуске тестов в 4 случаях из 10 получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Message:
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

В чем проблема понять не могу версии браузера и chromeDriver актуальные и совместимые (пробовал стаивть разные ничего не менялось).
Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Selenium чтоли? Ошибка возникает в вашем коде? Покажите код, укажите строку, где выбрасывается исключение. `Периодически` - это как расшифровывается? И винду бы вам обновить.

Comment: Тут проблема не думаю что в коде, так как именно не происходит старт браузера, шаг выполняется но сам браузер не запускается.